# android testing onActivityResult

Tags: android, testing

I am searching for a solution to get my test (which actually is an ActivityInstrumentationTextCase2) testing the onActivityResults method of my Activity with a special (mock) request- / resultcode and intent...

Code:
method should be tested:

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
        //In this case the user selected an image from his harddrive
        case StartupActivity.PICK_IMAGE:
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                this.processSelectedFile(data.getData());
            }
            break;
        }
    }
```

test class:

```
public void testOnActivityResult() {
        //here I would like to call the onActivityResult method from my mActivity object.
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried setting up your activity object and then just calling onActivityResult?

Comment: hey thanks for your answer - the onActivityResult is a protected method and therefor not visible in the test class...

Comment: Are you asking what code you should write in your "testOnActivityResult()" method? Or are you asking if your "onActivityResult" method does what you want it to, or how to validate that the data has been processed? I would imagine @weston's suggestion of setting up and calling the method would be the quickest way of testing if it's doing what you want it to do. Or are you looking to achieve more automated testing (Junit etc)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test a protected member, declare (in your test project) a new class that derives from your target:

```
public class TestMyActivity : MyActivity
{

  //constructors

   public void testOnActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { 
       //call super one
       super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
   }

}
```

Now in your test, create one of these and you can call the method.

Source of idea:

http://codebetter.com/karlseguin/2009/08/19/testing-protected-methods-is-easy/

Comment: This seems to be a good solution I can live with... Stupid that I did not come to the idea to google how to test a protected method! Probably because I looked at the problem from the wrong side. I will check this out now. Thanks a lot!!